# Unable to find text color inside the shapes

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

```
prs = Presentation('template.pptx')
c = 0
for slide in prs.slides:
    c = c+1
    print("slide no:",c)
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        line_fill = shape.line.fill
        tx = shape
        txt = shape.text
        s = txt.split()
        text_frame = shape.text_frame
        p = text_frame.paragraphs[0]
        p.text = str(s[0:1])
        color = p.font.color.type
        bold = p.font.bold
        print("color size", txt, color, bold)
        for run in p.runs:
            font = run.font
            font_bold = font.bold
            print("bold", font_bold)
            print("font color type ", font.color.type)
            if font.color.type == MSO_COLOR_TYPE.RGB:
                color = font.color.rgb
                print("color ", color)
```

When I am trying to retrieve the text colour inside the shape using font-color,the code is returns nothing!

Comment: Formatting tip: You can create multi-line code blocks using ``` instead of `.

Comment: font color is None unless a color has explicitly been assigned. This indicates it inherits its color from the style hierarchy. There is no API support for "effective" color.

Answer (score 0):

There are style properties for PowerPoint objects that may not be specified. In this case, the mechanism of inheritance of such properties from parent objects works. The actual properties of the object that will be applied in the end are sometimes called effective.

If you use [Aspose.Slides for Python](https://products.aspose.com/slides/python-net/), you will get the effective values of paragraph colors and paragraph part colors as shown below:

```py
import aspose.slides as slides

from aspose.slides import AutoShape
from aspose.slides import FillType

with slides.Presentation("template.pptx") as presentation:
    
    for slide_index, slide in enumerate(presentation.slides):
        print("slide No: ", slide_index + 1)

        for shape in slide.shapes:

            if isinstance(shape, AutoShape):

                for paragraph in shape.text_frame.paragraphs:

                    # Get an effective text fill format of the paragraph that has been set or inherited.
                    paragraph_format = paragraph.paragraph_format.get_effective().default_portion_format.fill_format

                    if paragraph_format.fill_type == FillType.SOLID:

                        # Get the color of a paragraph text.
                        paragraph_color = paragraph_format.solid_fill_color.name
                        print(paragraph.text, paragraph_color)

                        for portion in paragraph.portions:

                            # Get an effective text fill format of the paragraph portion.
                            portion_format = portion.portion_format.get_effective().fill_format

                            if portion_format.fill_type == FillType.SOLID:
                        
                                # Get the color of a paragraph portion.
                                portion_color = portion_format.solid_fill_color.name
                                print(portion.text, portion_color)
```

Alternatively, you could use [Aspose.Slides Cloud SDK for Python](https://products.aspose.cloud/slides/python/). This REST-based API allows you to make 150 free API calls per month for API learning and presentation processing. The following code example shows you how to get paragraph part colors using Aspose.Slides Cloud:

```py
import asposeslidescloud

from asposeslidescloud.apis.slides_api import SlidesApi

slides_api = SlidesApi(None, "my_client_id", "my_client_key")

file_name = "template.pptx"

# Request information about slides and get the slide count.
slide_count = len(slides_api.get_slides(file_name).slide_list)

for slide_index in range(1, slide_count + 1): # 1-based index for requests

    print("slide No: ", slide_index)

    # Request information about shapes and get the shape count.
    shape_count = len(slides_api.get_shapes(file_name, slide_index).shapes_links)

    for shape_index in range(1, shape_count + 1): # 1-based index for requests

        # Request information about paragraphs and get the paragraph count.
        paragraph_count = len(slides_api.get_paragraphs(file_name, slide_index, shape_index).paragraph_links)

        for paragraph_index in range(1, paragraph_count + 1): # 1-based index for requests

            # Request information about a paragraph.
            paragraph = slides_api.get_paragraph(file_name, slide_index, shape_index, paragraph_index)

            # Show text and color of portions.
            for portion in paragraph.portion_list:
                print(portion.text, portion.font_color)
```

I work as a Support Developer at Aspose.